# debug rails 3.1.1 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, rvm, ruby-1.9, ruby-debug

I'm try to add a debugger to my rails 3.1.1 application which uses ruby 1.9.2.  I have added the following to my gemfile:

```
gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

and I get the following error:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails31/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/interface.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in initialize': uninitialized constant Debugger::LocalInterface::Readline (NameError)
```

by the way i have the following:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]
$ rails -v
Rails 3.1.1
$ rvm -v
rvm 1.8.6 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
```

Answer (score 1):

What made is work for me is:

```
sudo gem install ruby-debug19
gem install linecache19
gem install ruby-debug-base19
bundle update
rails server -u
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you install all the prerequisites listed in `rvm notes` before you installed Ruby? I'm not positive, but I think readline is a dependency for MRI on Linux.

You may also follow [these instructions from the RVM site](http://beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/):

> If you have an error when compiling pertaining to readline, you may
>   need to attempt installing with the procedure defined below.
>
> NOTE: Before you follow the procedure below please be sure to verify
>   that you have installed any dependencies for the Ruby you are
>   installing listed by the 'rvm notes' command. If you have not yet done
>   that do so then run 'rvm remove X ; rvm install X' where X is the Ruby
>   that you are concerned with.
>
> ```
> $ rvm pkg install readline
> $ rvm remove 1.9.2
> $ rvm install 1.9.2 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response the error changed to:


    `You need to install ruby-debug to run the server in debugging mode. With gems, use 'gem install ruby-debug'`
    `Exiting`

Comment: Just to double-check, now that you can install the gem, have you run a `bundle install` on your project?

Comment: yep it didn't seem to change anything