# Using capybara-firebug "stop and let me debug" in ruby 1.9.3

Tags: cucumber, ruby-debug

I have just upgrade to ruby on rails 3.0.9 from using rails 2.X.
I have been writing feature tests in cucumber and used the capybara-firebug gem and specifically the included step `stop and let me debug` frequently to debug.

However after the update I keep getting a error saying:

```
When stop and let me debug          # capybara-firebug-1.2.3/lib/capybara/firebug.rb:52
  cannot load such file -- ruby-debug (LoadError)
```

My research sofar has led me to that the problem has to do with ruby-debug gem that does not work with ruby 1.9.3 wich I am currently using.

I tried an alternative, debugger but now I am stuck with a problem when running tests, EVEN after uninstalling debugger as I read that ruby-debug19 should be a better alternative.

This is the error I get now when running tests:

```
uninitialized constant Debugger::LocalInterface::Readline (NameError)
```

How do I get rid of that and get the debug to work properly again?

Comment: Have you included the `ruby-debug19` gem which is required with `ruby 1.9.3 version` ? it's not very clear from the question.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy Yes I did. But the Readline error returned when I did that. I got it working now though. Was a problem with readline gem that when installed properly the ruby-debug19 worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you're using `rvm` or not. But I think you're possibly missing a `gem`. If using `rvm`, confirm that `readline` is installed:

```
% rvm pkg install readline
```

Next confirm that `ruby-debug19` is installed correctly:

```
% gem install ruby-debug19
% gem install linecache19
% gem install ruby-debug-base19
```

**SOURCE:** this SO question/answer: [debug rails 3.1.1 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802124/debug-rails-3-1-1-application)

Comment: As I commented to PrakashMurthy this was the problem. But the strange thing is that the Error message still mentioned Debugger though it was uninstalled. But this is how I solved it so I will give you the reward and correct.